# Find "Span" that is within "div" in HTML using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to find the text that is within this span here using JSoup:
`<div class="_6wab"><span>$35 raised</span>`

I have successfully gotten text within a divider that looks like this:
`<div class="_6wae">Time</div>`

Using this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://" + line).userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
String goal = doc.select("div._6wae").html();
```

So I know my method works for finding a text within a divider, but I'm not sure how to find the text within a span, within a divider.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might work.

Primarily, find the first div with class '_6wab'.

```
Element div = doc.getElementsByClass("_6wab").first();
```

Then, after getting the div, find the inner span.

```
  Element span = div.select("span").first();
```

Finally, get the text.

```
System.out.println(span.text());
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, it doesn't NPE at the first line you sent me, but when I try to do div.select it throws an NPE.

Likewise when I try to do system.out.println(div().html().tostring); it npes.

Comment: Make sure if there is an element with class _6wab, otherwise, a Null Pointer will be thrown.

Comment: You're right! I didn't realize the div was semi-dynamic. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to NPE in case the class doesn't exist, if there are multiple `span`s within the div, this will only select the first.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=_6wab><span>$35 raised</span></div><p><span>hi</span></p>");
//use css selectors
Elements rows = doc.select("div._6wab span");
System.out.println(rows.eachText());
```

outputs:

```
[$35 raised]
```

Note only the text within the span within the div is printed. Also, no `NullPointerException` will be thrown if the class doesn't exist in the HTML. In that case, an empty list will be returned. This will also catch *all* spans within the div with the given class.

Comment: I updated it to use css selectors like you would do in javascript.